# Bootstrap DateTimePicker на WP

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bootstrap, datetimepicker

[image: Как выглядит календарь на сайте]

```
//init DateTimePickers
        if( $('.wpes-datepicker').length > 0 ) {
            $('.wpes-datepicker').each( function() {
                locale: 'ru'
    
                var dateFormat = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
                if( $(this).attr('date-format') ) {
                    dateFormat = $(this).attr('date-format');
                }
        
                $( this ).datetimepicker({
                    format: dateFormat,
                    useCurrent: false,
                    icons: {
                        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                        date: "fa fa-calendar",
                        up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
                        down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
                        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
                        next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
                        today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
                        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
                        close: 'fa fa-remove'
                    }
                } );
            } );
        }
```

Код в шаблоне на wordpress, календарь на английском языке, как сделать на русском?

Comment: https://wpcute.ru/blog/kak-skorrektirovat-perevod-wordpress-temyi-ili-plagina-pod-sebya/

Comment: Плагин Loco Translate стоит, но он не видит этот календарь, так как его элементов(месяца, дни) нет в коде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел в файле bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

Там руками отредактировал строки:

```
Ht="Воскресенье_Понедельник_Вторник_Среда_Четверг_Пятница_Суббота".split("_"),Lt="Вск_Пнд_Втр_Сре_Чтв_Птн_Суб".split("_"),Gt="Вс_Пн_Вт_Ср_Чт_Пт_Сб"
```

Answer (score 0):

После строки

`$( this ).datetimepicker({`

добавьте

`language: 'ru',`

Comment: Форма вообще перестает реагировать

Comment: Весьма сомнительно. Смотрите ошибки в консоли и покажите их тут.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: option language is not recognized!
    at String.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js?ver=1.1.0:48)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at Object.f.options (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js?ver=1.1.0:48)
    at a (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js?ver=1.1.0:48)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js?ver=1.1.0:48)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at s.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at s.fn.init.e.fn.datetimepicker (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js?ver=1.1.0:48)

Comment: at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (script.js?ver=1.1.0:286)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)

Comment: Код ваш покажите и сообщение об ошибке, вместе в окне браузера

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать следующий код:

```
$.datetimepicker.setLocale('ru');
```

Пример:

```
var localeCode = "ru";
$.datetimepicker.setLocale(localeCode);

var startDate = $('#startDate');
var endDate = $('#endDate');
startDate.datetimepicker({
    timepicker: false,
    format: 'Y-m-d',
    formatDate: 'Y-m-d',
    onShow: function (ct) {
        this.setOptions({
            maxDate: endDate.val() ? endDate.val() : false
        })
    }
});
endDate.datetimepicker({
    timepicker: false,
    format: 'Y-m-d',
    formatDate: 'Y-m-d',
    onShow: function (ct) {
        this.setOptions({
            minDate: startDate.val() ? startDate.val() : false
        })
    }
});

var startTime = $('#startTime');
var endTime = $('#endTime');
startTime.datetimepicker({
    datepicker: false,
    format: 'H:i',
    onShow: function (ct) {
        this.setOptions({
            maxTime: endTime.val() ? endTime.val() : false
        })
    }
});
endTime.datetimepicker({
    datepicker: false,
    format: 'H:i',
    onShow: function (ct) {
        this.setOptions({
            minTime: startTime.val() ? startTime.val() : false
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Форма вообще перестает реагировать

Comment: @Beger посмотрите пример, я дополнил, это с реальной существующей работающей таблицы. Если у вас не работает, то что-то ещё не так на вашей стороне...

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLocale' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (script.js?ver=1.1.0:281)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at s.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js?ver=1.1.0:278)
    at e (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)